# knife search nodes based on cookbook::recipe

Tags: chef-infra

Trying to search the nodes with a specified cookbook and recipe on node, but it show the following error:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/lbsvc/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

Net::HTTPServerException
------------------------
400 "Bad Request"
...    
Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/lbsvc/recipes/loadbalancer.rb:

 12:  template "/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg" do
 13:    source "haproxy.cfg.erb"
 14:    owner "haproxy"
 15:    group "haproxy"
 16:    variables({
 17:      gw_nodes: search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND recipe:realdoc-gateway").sort_by{ |n| n.name },
 18>>     microservice_nodes: search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND recipes:'microservice::loadbalancer'").sort_by{ |n| n.name },
 19:      microservice2_nodes: search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND recipes:'microservice2::loadbalancer'").sort_by{ |n| n.name },
 20:      ui_nodes: search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND recipe:vault-ui").sort_by{ |n| n.name }
 21:    }) 
 22:    notifies :reload, 'service[haproxy]'
 23:  end    

Running handlers:
[2016-09-04T13:30:26+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-09-04T13:30:26+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-09-04T13:30:26+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 5.477354028 seconds
[2016-09-04T13:30:26+00:00] ERROR: 400 "Bad Request"
[2016-09-04T13:30:26+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

It shows the error here `recipes:microservice\:\:loadbalancer`, somehow I'm not using this correctly even if I got the syntax from chefdocs.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: │Net::HTTPServerException 400 "Bad Request"...../var/chef/cache/cookbooks/lbsvc/recipes/loadbalancer.rb:18:in `block in from_file'

Comment: Any more details? Please include it. It might be that your lucene query is invalid or a general issue with your Chef Server.

Comment: If I leaveonly recipe:microservice is working... on these nodes i got both "recipe[microservice]" and "recipe[microservice::loadbalancer]"

Comment: it's chef 11 and everything it's working until I try to specify the recipe and the cookbook also so it's clear to me that it;s a syntax error

Comment: I assume the escaping of `::` causes your issues. Have you tried only `::` as well as `\\:\\:`?

Comment: I tried both scenarios and setting 'cookbook::recipe' in commas''

Comment: Please include your complete error output.

Comment: Please find the complete output in my answer below. Thanks

Comment: What about an edit?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Update your question instead of posting additional information as an answer. I did that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using double quotes (`"`), you have to double-escape (`\\`) the colon:

```ruby
search(:node, "recipes:microservice\\:\\:loadbalancer")
```

When using single quotes, one backslash is sufficient.

```ruby
search(:node, 'recipes:microservice\:\:loadbalancer')
```

Comment: I've done the changes and the error is still there unfortuantely.

Comment: In the same line? Are you _really_ sure? I verified the point of this myself.

Comment: Try to create a minimal example and put it on Github maybe.

Comment: It worked only with double "" \\:\\: and with RECIPE not with RECIPES. This is strange. Many appreciations

Comment: `recipe` should match the run list (roles and recipes assigned in the node object), and `recipes` the _expanded_  run list (includes all recipes added through roles and `include_recipe`). Read more about [run lists](https://docs.chef.io/run_lists.html).

Comment: Notably `recipes` (and `roles`) won't work until at least one node has succeeded and reported back to the Chef Server, and similarly won't find the current node on its first converge.